# No access for user to shared libraries

Tags: permissions, shared-library

I use Debian and I have a problem with executing `arm-none-eabi-gdb` as a user. I get the following message: `arm-none-eabi-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. The only way to run it is to type `sudo arm-none-eabi-gdb` . I have checked library libncurses.so.5 and found that there was no execute permission for users so I changed it with `chmod`. Now all users can execute it but I still get the error when calling `arm-none-eabi-gdb`  without sudo.

Can anyone explain me what is the mechanism that is blocking me ?

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved. It occurred that `arm-none-eabi-gdb` command was executing gdb program located in  different directory than `sudo arm-none-eabi-gdb` (surprisingly I had 2 arm-none-eabi-gdbs). `strace` helped me to solve the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a permission problem. That would explain why with `sudo` (i.e. working as "root") has no problems finding and using the shared library but your normal user cannot.

I assume that you have a symbolic link from `libncurses.so.5` to the actual version used in the system. The result of `ls -l` of that would be very helpful to know where the link points and its mode (permission), also check the permissions of the path.

Symbolic links on libraries work fine, as long as the final target they trace to exists and **is accessible**.

Comment: I have changed mod of all symbolic links and actual version, I have also checked permission of the path and it is executable for users. I still have not solved the issue.

Comment: @AlBundy If the permissions are now discarded as source of the problem, maybe it is the environment. Check the contents of the environment variables PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH (the last one might not be set) and compare between your user and root.

Comment: `arm-none-eabi-gdb` is inside /opt/.../ , `libncurses.so.5` inside /lib/.../ PATH for user: `/home/mkru/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` LD_LIBRARY_PATH for user: ` ` . PATH for root: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` LD_LIBRARY_PATH for root: ` ` .